# Playa Search Filter Goes to Blank Screen

Tags: playa, search, filter

I am running playa 4.4.5 and expression engine 2.8.1.  In my entries, when I try to search and filter entries in playa, no results will display with the ajax instead it is going to index.php?/cp/content_publish/entry_form?channel_id=7&entry_id=8539&&filter=YToxOntzOjEwOiJjaGFubmVsX2lkIjtzOjE6IjciO30= .  Which is all blank.  Can anyone help me here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was being sent to my index.php page instead of my news.php page.  I put this in the config file and it worked
`$config['playa_site_index'] = "/news.php";`